# is it normal for image inputs to be omitted from the DOM in document.forms[x].elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, forms, input

I've found that given a form in a HTML page like this:

```
<form name="form">
   <input type="image" name="foo" 
          src="somewhere.gif" alt="image" value="blah"/>
   <input type="text" name="bar" value="blah"/>
</form>
```

When accessing the elements via the DOM in Javascript, there is *no* element for the image input!  It is just omitted.  So, `document.forms[0].elements.length` is 1, and `document.forms[0].element[0].type` is "text".

This seems to be the case in Firefox, and IE.  I can't find this fact documented anywhere in  my reference books or on the web.  All I can find is a throwaway comment here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163822#c4

Which suggests it "just is like this".  If so, well so be it - but is it *really* not documented anywhere? Is it a historical mistake, or is there a reason for it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that's the behavior of the `elements` property in all browsers.

However, you should still be able to access it through the DOM in JavaScript using the `childNodes` property.

For your example:

```
document.forms[0].childNodes.length; // equals 5 (2 inputs and 3 text nodes).
document.forms[0].childNodes[1];     // This is your input with type='image'
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... the [DOM 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html) spec defines `.elements` as:

> elements
>       Returns a collection of all control elements in the form.

The [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#input-control-types) spec part 17.2.1 doesn't list "image" types, so I guess that's the answer.

Comment: True, but then it doesn't list the `textarea`, or `select` "inputs", and they *do* appear in the `.element` property

Comment: The HTML spec you link to _does_ list image types (between submit and reset), unless I don't understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I see a comment: "*The DOM is supposed to work that way, that's how it works in Mozilla, NS4x, and IE. We can't change that even if we wanted to, lots of sites would break.*" so I would lean toward an historical error. Image element is already in HTML 2 DTD...

Perhaps that's for that and possible other culprits that authors discourage using Dom hierarchy like that in favor of getElement[s]ByXxx functions (or XPath!).

Answer (score 0):

Been bitten by it myself. It's [stated in the MSDN DHTML docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826022(v=vs.85).aspx).