# Javascript elements.length returning wrong count?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Ok, been scratching my head on this one for a bit now... seems [related to this ol' chestnut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246966/is-it-normal-for-image-inputs-to-be-omitted-from-the-dom-in-document-formsx-ele)

Here's my problem:

```
var testlength = theForm.elements.length;
var testlastelement = theForm.elements[testlength].type;
```

testlength returns 60
BUT!
testlastelement comes back as "undefined" (null or not an object)

What gives?

FWIW, my page has a bunch of inputs (i'm trying to loop through a form and grab names, values, etc)... the form inputs are contained within a table but the last elements (which are also types=image) are outside that table.

Comment: 60 would be outside the array of size 60. last element ends at lenght[59]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays and HTMLCollections like [form.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) in JavaScript have 0-based indexes, that means you have 60 elements, and their indexes are from 0 to 59, or from 0 to length-1

Comment: Got it! The length is 60 but it goes from 0 - 59. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Use `testlength - 1`. Arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first element of an array has the index 0, therefore you should try this:

```
var testlastelement = theForm.elements[testlength-1].type;
```

Comment: Ok, cool. I get that... but... confusion still reigns... theForm.elements[0] returns a valid element. So what is the length property counting? length = 60, 0 = my 1st element, 60 = ???. My loop no longer errors using the -1 approach... but that's 'cuz it skips the 1st element. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need testlength-1, since arrays are zeo-indexed. That is:

```
var testlastelement = theForm.elements[testlength-1].type;
```

Also, camelcase is the javascript standard. Probably better to write this as:

```
var testLastElement = theForm.elements[testLength-1].type;
```

At least be consistent. Your variable theForm is camelcased.

Comment: Thanks! yeah, i'm a newb... but im learnin'! 

Still scratching my head on the length count thing though... see above.